# Specify subnets for EKS cluster created with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks, subnet

I am creating an EKS cluster in Terraform. Within my EKS terraform resource, I am specifying subnet IDs that were also created with Terraform. Below is the resource I have for the subnets:

```
resource “aws_subnet” “public” {
  count = length(local.availability_zone_names)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.eks_vpc.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 12, count.index + 1)
  availability_zone = local.availability_zone_names[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = “${var.application}-${terraform.workspace}-PublicSubnet${count.index + 1}”
  }
}

resource “aws_subnet” “private” {
  count = length(local.availability_zone_names)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.eks_vpc.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 12, count.index + 4)
  availability_zone = local.availability_zone_names[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = {
    Name = “${var.application}-${terraform.workspace}-PrivateSubnet${count.index + 1}”
  }
}
```

Below is the resource I have for the EKS cluster:

```
resource “aws_eks_cluster” “eks_cluster” {
  name = “${var.application}-${terraform.workspace}”
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.eks_control_plane_sg.id,
      aws_security_group.eks_cluster_sg.id
    ]

    subnet_ids = [
      local.private_subnet_ids[count.index],
      local.public_subnet_ids[count.index]
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is local variables I have set up:

```
locals {
  availability_zone_names = data.aws_availability_zones.availability_zones.names
  public_subnet_ids = aws_subnet.public.*.id
  private_subnet_ids = aws_subnet.private.*.id
}
```

The error I am getting deals with the reference to the “count” object. Since I am using the count object to create these subnets, I am unable to use “count.index” in the resource for the eks cluster. Below is the error. Any advice on how to get past this would be helpful.

```
Error: Reference to “count in non-counted context

on eks.tf line 17, in resource “aws_eks_cluster” “eks_cluster”:
17: local.public_subnet_ids[count.index]

The “count” object can only be used in “module”, “resource”, and “data” blocks, and only when the “count” argument is set.
```

I am not using the count object in the eks cluster resource because I only want to create 1 cluster. Any advice on how to specify the subnets in this eks cluster resource would be helpful.

Comment: Could you use `terraform-aws-eks` for this?

Comment: You cannot use `local.private_subnet_ids[count.index]` or `local.public_subnet_ids[count.index]` as there is no `count` meta-argument in `aws_eks_cluster` resource. Can you try with `subnet_ids = concat(aws_subnet.public.*.id, aws_subnet.private.*.id)`?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Additional question. I already have the EKS cluster running, but only on private subnets. If I also add public subnets on top of private ones, would it recreate the cluster or just modify it? I am not sure how terraform would behave. Does anybody have an idea? @Marcin

Comment: @Shank Please make proper SO question specific to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concat](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/concat) to construct `subnet_ids`:

```
resource “aws_eks_cluster” “eks_cluster” {
  name = “${var.application}-${terraform.workspace}”
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.eks_control_plane_sg.id,
      aws_security_group.eks_cluster_sg.id
    ]

    subnet_ids = concat(local.private_subnet_ids,  local.public_subnet_ids)
    ]
  }
}
```